# What gesture recogniser does Photo app use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

What gesture recogniser should I use if I want to the user to swipe between 2 UIView's in the same way they swipe between photos in the Photo app?  No the zooming just the transition between 2 photos.

Should I use the swipe or the pan gesture?

I am also using this with the UIPageControl so that when they swipe the page changes and the new view is visible.

Comment: Why not using UIScrollView with pagingEnabled YES?

Comment: Its a swipe gesture on a scrollview. No need for a gesture recognizer. Just subclass UIScrollView and override -(void) scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent check the delta.x ooops! sorry thats for OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you use no gesture recogniser, instead you have to implement your own dragging method in scroll view delegate methods. Look at Apple's code they have written for this; http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/PageControl.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think It would be better to use swipe gesture recognizer.I have used same way with UIPagecontrol and its working smoothly.